# Can I do pub/sub of events in Java natively (and is this JMS?)?

Tags: java, events, architecture, publish-subscribe

Background:
I'm trying to develop an application and I'm not quite sure of the java technologies I need to look into. The basic outline of my problem is this:

Let's say that I'm developing an application that programmatically "watches" something (let's call it a football game). I want to create any number of algorithms that read that thing (let's say they're football passes) (which I assume I'll run as "threads" in the main process so that many can run simultaneously). I want those algorithms to spit out "events" (which I'm assuming I want to create as POJOs - extending the java event class?) that get published to a generic pub/sub manager. I then want some algorithms (again, "threads"?) that can subscribe to events they're interested in (possibly multiple ones) and then act upon them (such as totalling the number of forward passes by a team).

Question:
I feel like this is a combination of the java concepts I've described above (threads running in a process, producing objects based on a class that extends the EventObject class) but, am I right in thinking that I do pub/sub through JMS?

Cheers

Comment: Yes, pub/sub messaging belongs to JMS.

Comment: I think my confusion lies in the "messaging" part of JMS. The documentation looks like it's a message structure (like http messages with header and body etc) whereas I want to be able to send classes (more specifically "events") rather than messages

Comment: `JMS 2.0` is Java Messaging Service as defined in [`JSR-343`](https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr343/index.html). It's fully implemented in the latest versions of `GlassFish` and `WildFly`. If you expect server support then you need to adhere to the standard.